# Como ocultar e bloquear a última linha de um JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

É possível ocultar e bloquear a última linha de um `DefaulTableModel`?

Estou com essa dificuldade e não estou conseguindo resolver. Se não for ao menos é possível ocultar essa linha?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Main extends JFrame {
  DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][] {
       {"Jack","19","Masculino"}, {"Eddie","56","Masculino"}, {"Gina","34","Feminino"},
      {"Klaus","18","Masculino"}, {"Erika","20","Feminino"},  {"Roberto","29","Masculino"},{"Maria","30","Feminino"} },
      new Object[] { "Nome:", "Idade:", "Sexo:" });

  public Main() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JTable table = new JTable(model);
    getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    pack();
  }

  public static void main(String arg[]) {
    new Main().setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Gostaria de ocultar a última linha.

Comment: Bom.. É necessário um exemplo minimo, completo e verificável, par uma pergunta se é possivel bloquear uma linha de uma tabela qualquer? se a tabela tem 5 linhas, é possível bloquear a ultima? desculpe a pergunta, é meu primeiro tópico.

Comment: E onde está seu tablemodel? Que linha precisa ser bloqueada? Quando ela precisa ser bloqueada?

Comment: coloquei um exemplo de tablemodel, eu preciso que a ultima linha seja ocultada assim que abrir a frame, só preciso q ela seja oculta

Comment: Atualizei a resposta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se com "bloquear" você quer dizer  evitar que os dados da linha sejam editados, basta sobrescrever o método [`isCellEditable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#isCellEditable-int-int-) do `TableModel` da seguinte forma:

```
DefaultTableModel model =  new DefaultTableModel(dados, colunas) {

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return row < (getRowCount() - 1);
    }
}

table=new JTable(model);
```

Este método retorna um booleano para cada célula(cruzamento linha x coluna) da tabela, informando se os dados dela podem ser editados ou não. A lógica acima retornará true enquanto o indice da linha for menor que o da última linha.

Mas não faz muito sentido bloquear uma linha se não quer nem exibi-la. O método acima já evita que a mesma seja alterada pelo usuário.

O exemplo apresentado também é muito genérico, não apresenta de fato um problema a ser resolvido. Se quer ocultar uma linha, a forma menos complicada é removendo ela na tabela com o método [`removeRow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#removeRow-int-), passando seu índice.

---

Se mesmo assim quiser insistir em ocultar a linha já estando bloqueada, **é possivel se a tabela já possuir um** [**TableRowSorter**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableRowSorter.html) e você criar um [`RowFilter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html) que filtre as linhas a serem exibidas na tabela, de forma que quando for a última, não exiba:

```
RowFilter<TableModel, Integer> filter = new RowFilter<TableModel, Integer>(){

    @Override
    public boolean include(javax.swing.RowFilter.Entry<? extends TableModel, ? extends Integer> entry) {
        int modelRow = entry.getIdentifier();
        return modelRow < (table.getRowCount() - 1);
    }
};

...

((TableRowSorter<?>)table.getRowSorter()).setRowFilter(filter);
```

O método `include` retorna um booleano se determinada entrada pode ser exibida na tabela, neste caso, estou retorna true para todos os casos onde o indice da linha do `TableModel` for menor que o da última linha. Ela continua existindo no model, mas não é exibida na view.

Na [tutorial da Oracle sobre JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) você pode ler mais a respeito de como criar e aplicar filtros e ordenar linhas de tabelas.

Comment: Agradeço pela sua resposta, eu estou tentando contornar uma situação em que eu preciso adicionar  uma linha vazia e para q ela n fique visível eu queria oculta-la

Comment: @Lucas16 nenhuma solução que eu sugerir baseado nesse código genérico vai te ajudar. Se você seguir a lógica do código da resposta, independente do que seja a ultima linha, ela jamais será exibida. E se a linha a ser oculta em algum  momento deixar de ser a ultima? Não da pra sugerir nada sem ter uma representação real do seu problema.

Comment: Sim, mas eu precisava oculta-la, simplesmente oculta-la na jtable, teria como vc me da um exemplo de oculta-la?

Comment: @Lucas16 é só você sobrescrever o metodo getValueAt do defaulTableModel, verificando se a linha atual é a ultima, com a mesma lógica que usei na resposta.

Comment: Seria um incomodo se vc me da esse exemplo? talvez seja útil para outra pessoal também. fiquei um pouco confuso.

Comment: @Lucas16 já está na resposta. Basta adicionar `model.removeRow(totalDeLinhas-1)`. Só que isso removerá permanentemente essa linha.

Comment: mas eu quero ocultar a linha, não remove-la kkkkkk....

Comment: @Lucas16 a solução de bloqueio e ocultação sugeridas não serviram? Se sim, você pode marcar a pergunta como concluida, clicando no  `v` ao lado da resposta.

Comment: Me desculpe, eu fiquei ausente e me esqueci quando voltei, perdão cara. Deu super certo!